# Using ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET (UWP)

Tags: arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I am new to GIS and trying to create a map in my UWP app. I have a working MapView and used SketchEditor to enable drawing polygons, points, polylines etc. However, can someone please explain why I get a wkt string like

```
PROJCS["WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",0.0],PARAMETER["Auxiliary_Sphere_Type",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

instead of something like

```
POLYGON((571178 6337246,571178 6402217,598061 6402217,598061 6337246,571178 6337246))
```

My code below:

```
var coloradoCorners = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.PointCollection(SpatialReferences.Wgs84);
coloradoCorners.Add(-109.048, 40.998);
coloradoCorners.Add(-102.047, 40.998);
coloradoCorners.Add(-102.037, 36.989);
coloradoCorners.Add(-109.048, 36.998);

// create a new polygon from the point collection
var coloradoPoly = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.Polygon(coloradoCorners);
string wktString = coloradoPoly.SpatialReference.WkText();
```

Gives the string:

```
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]
```

The map I have coded is:

```
 private void Initialize()
        {
            var myNewMap = new Map(
                            BasemapType.Imagery, // use the Imagery basemap
                            42.175131,           // latitude
                            9.192313,            // longitude
                            8                    // level of detail (lower number = smaller scale)
                            );

            // Create graphics overlay to display sketch geometry
            _sketchOverlay = new GraphicsOverlay();
            MyMapView.GraphicsOverlays.Add(_sketchOverlay);

            // Assign the map to the MapView
            MyMapView.Map = myNewMap;

            // Fill the combo box with choices for the sketch modes (shapes)
            SketchModeComboBox.ItemsSource = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(SketchCreationMode));
            SketchModeComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;

            // Set the sketch editor as the page's data context
            DataContext = MyMapView.SketchEditor;
        }
```

and to draw a polygon:

```
SketchCreationMode creationMode = (SketchCreationMode)SketchModeComboBox.SelectedItem;
                Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.Geometry geometry = await MyMapView.SketchEditor.StartAsync(creationMode, true);

                // Create and add a graphic from the geometry the user drew
                Graphic graphic = CreateGraphic(geometry);
                _sketchOverlay.Graphics.Add(graphic);
```

Comment: Hi Ellie, where do you get the first string? That is not a geometry wkt, it is projection string.

Comment: @HekkiVesanto Hi there, I am doing the following:

var coloradoCorners = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.PointCollection(SpatialReferences.Wgs84);
            coloradoCorners.Add(-109.048, 40.998);
            coloradoCorners.Add(-102.047, 40.998);
            coloradoCorners.Add(-102.037, 36.989);
            coloradoCorners.Add(-109.048, 36.998);

// create a new polygon from the point collection
var coloradoPoly = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.Polygon(coloradoCorners);
var test =  coloradoPoly.SpatialReference.WkText;

Comment: That looks correct. You are calling: coloradoPoly.SpatialReference.WkText; So you should get the SpatialReference in a text format. If you want the polygon you could try: coloradoPoly.WkText;

Comment: I did think that, but there is not .WkText on the Polygon GeometryType...

Comment: What about  coloradoPoly.ToString might need coloradoPoly.ToString()

Comment: That returns Polygon[Parts=1, Points=4, Wkid=4326], do I need to build the geometry wkt string from this? I was hoping it would be built in

Comment: You could try the JSON representation: coloradoPoly.ToJson();

Comment: I have also tried this with no luck...

Comment: I would edit the question with the code in your comments and the results of ToString, and ToJson, you might get someone to answer who has worked with the ESRI API. Sorry I couldn't be of more assistance, good luck.